Construct PCP instance for given Index list
Given an index list I and an Alphabet E, i want to construct the two lists of words a and b s.t. I is the shortest solution for the post correspondence problem on a and b, i.e., find a,b s.t. PCP(a,b) = I.
Any ideas for an algorithm?

Do you need $I$ to be the shortest solution or a shortest solution? (meaning do you need unicity of the solution).

Also I don't think this is always possible. For example, if $[1, 1]$ is a solution to the PCP with $(a, b)$, then $[1]$ is a shorter solution.

@Nathaniel one solution is enough, no unicity required. You're correct, i did not think of such cases. For my application, i think those cases are neglectable, but good to keep them in mind!

Partial answer here.
Let $n$ be the maximum between $|I|$ and the maximum index of $I$ plus one. Then $set(I)$ is a subset of $[\![0, n-1]\!]$. Note that I differentiate $I$ (with order and repetitions) and $set(I)$ (the set of elements in $I$). For $i\in [\![0, n-1]\!]$, denote $occ(i)$ the number of occurrences of $i$ in $I$.
I construct an input $(a, b)$ with shortest solution $I$ in the case where there is some $i$ such that $occ(i) = 1$. As stated in the comment of OP's question, I think that not any $I$ can be a shortest solution.
The idea of the construction is to consider that words are decompositions in base $n$.
Let $a, b\in E$ be two letters, with $a \neq b$ in the case $|E| > 1$. Create the words as follow:

if $i\in I$, $u_i = a^{n^i-1}b$;
if $i\notin I$, $u_i = a^{n^n}$;
for some $i_0\in I$ such that $occ(i_0) = 1$, $v_{i_0}= \bigodot\limits_{i\in I}u_i$, where $\bigodot$ is the concatenation;
for $i\neq i_0$, $v_i = \varepsilon$.

Then for $u = (u_0,u_1,…,u_{n-1})$ and $v=(v_0,v_1,…,v_{n-1})$, $I$ is the shortest solution to $\mathsf{PCP}(u, v)$. This works using the uniqueness of the decomposition of an integer in base $n$, and using the fact that no carry is possible, because of the definition of $n$.
Indeed, since all $u_i\neq \varepsilon$, for a solution to exist, it is necessary to select $i_0$. But $|v_{i_0}| = \sum\limits_{i\in set(I)}occ(i)n^i<n^n$. That means that each $i\in [\![0,n-1]\!]$ needs to be selected $occ(i)$ times. The positions of $b$'s forces the order of indices in the case of $|E|>1$ (and there are multiple solutions in the case $|E| = 1$).
